# Dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu with UEFI on two separate drives?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I've already installed Windows 8 in UEFI mode and it is currently running off of one SSD. On another SSD, I want to install Ubuntu GNOME. Is there any sort of special configuration or setting I have to choose in my BIOS?

The Windows 8 installation is installed in UEFI mode and the entry for it in my BIOS is Windows Boot Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd recommend installing Ubuntu MATE (the supported remake of GNOME for modern versions of Ubuntu), but aside from that you should be fine. GRUB should recognize Windows automatically. Just make sure, if you can, to boot into the Ubuntu installer in EFI mode. You'll also want to set the SSD that Ubuntu is on to be before the Windows drive.

Comment: I tried booting the USB with every compatibility thing turned off to force UEFI and it went to a black screen. With compatibility turned on, the installation runs fine up to installing GRUB, in which case it fails.

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. You do need the Ubuntu drive to be on SATA 0, or the first hardware drive.

Comment: Didn't know that. Will try.